# Multi-term Lucene query returning 0 results

Tags: azure, lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lucene as a full text engine for a SQL Azure database, and I'm having a hard time figuring out what I did wrong.

The following query returns a document as expected:

```
(Title:stray Content:stray Tag:stray)~1
```

It returns a document with the Title: "This Stray Dog Was Hit By A Car. You'll Be Shocked To See Who Saved The Day."

But this query returns 0 documents:

```
(Title:stray dog Content:stray dog Tag:stray dog)~1
```

I'm using Lucene.Net if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes round "stray dog". Otherwise, you've got four bits:

1. Title:stray
2. dog
3. Content: stray
4. dog

which isn't what you meant, I don't think!

On the other hand, if you want to search for either "stray" or "dog", rather than the phrase "stray dog", then use parentheses instead of quotes:

```
Title:(stray dog) Content:(stray dog) Tag:(stray dog)
```

Comment: but I want to search for both words, so it should match an article about "pure bread dogs" or "stray cats". Am I doing that wrong?

Comment: Ah, in that case you want to put parentheses round "stray dog". Use "Title:(stray dog) Content:(stray dog) Tag:(stray dog)"

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the parentheses bit.